# get the specific record from nsarray

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray

hello In  nsarray the data is like this

```
(
        {
        Trip =         {

            "trip_id" = 41;
            "trip_post_date" = "2016-03-28 07:52:19";

            "user_id" = 65;
        };
        User =         {

            "first_name" = irfan;
            "last_name" = sheikh;

            "user_id" = 65;
        };
        "arrival_country" =         {
            "city_name" = "Feldkirchen in Karnten";
            "country_name" = Austria;
            id = 272221;

        };
        "departure_country" =         {
            "city_name" = "Colonia La Tordilla";
            "country_name" = Argentina;
            id = 1234057;

        };
    },
        {
        Trip =         {

            "trip_id" = 40;
            "trip_post_date" = "2016-03-28 07:50:48";

            "user_id" = 65;
        };
        User =         {

            "first_name" = irfan;
            "last_name" = sheikh;


        };
        "arrival_country" =         {
            "city_name" = Karachi;
            "country_name" = Pakistan;
            id = 67008;

        };
        "departure_country" =         {
            "city_name" = Lahore;
            "country_name" = Pakistan;
            id = 112623;

        };
    }
)
```

how can I get only that record which has trip id which I give. like from the code how  can I  get that record which has `trip_id` 41

Comment: please add some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `NSPredicate` to filter your object from `NSArray`. Following snippet will find object from Nested Array.

**JSON**

```
NSArray *tripAarray  = @[
 @{@"Trip":@{
             @"trip_id" : @"41",
             @"trip_post_date" : @"2016-03-28 07:52:19",
             @"user_id" : @65
     },
     @"User" :@{
             @"first_name" : @"irfan",
             @"last_name" : @"sheikh",
             @"user_id" : @65
     },
     @"arrival_country" :@{
             @"city_name" : @"Feldkirchen in Karnten",
             @"country_name" : @"Austria",
             @"id" : @272221
     },
     @"departure_country" :@{
             @"city_name" : @"Colonia La Tordilla",
             @"country_name" : @"Argentina",
             @"id" : @1234057
     }
   },
 @{@"Trip":@{
           @"trip_id" : @"42",
           @"trip_post_date" : @"2016-03-28 07:52:19",
           @"user_id" : @65
           },
   @"User" :@{
           @"first_name" : @"irfan",
           @"last_name" : @"sheikh",
           @"user_id" : @65
           },
   @"arrival_country" :@{
           @"city_name" : @"Feldkirchen in Karnten",
           @"country_name" : @"Austria",
           @"id" : @272221
           },
   @"departure_country" :@{
           @"city_name" : @"Colonia La Tordilla",
           @"country_name" : @"Argentina",
           @"id" : @1234057
           }
   }];
```

**Objective-C**

```
// Create a Predicate with mapping to trip_id 
NSPredicate *filterByTrip = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K.%K CONTAINS[c] %@", @"Trip",@"trip_id",@"41"];   

// Filter your main array with predicate, resulting array will have filtered objects 
NSArray *filteredArray = [tripAarray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterByTrip];

NSLog(@"%@",filteredArray);
```

**Swift**

```
// Create a Predicate with mapping to trip_id
var filterByTrip: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K.%K CONTAINS[c] %@", "Trip", "trip_id", @"41")

// Filter your main array with predicate, resulting array will have filtered objects
var filteredArray: [AnyObject] = tripAarray.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(filterByTrip)
NSLog("%@", filteredArray)
```

Comment: sorry Can You tell me how to do this in swift ?

Comment: This is the error I am getting 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an NSArray or an NSSet.'

Comment: What object type are you passing to filter? It should be `NSArray` or `NSSet` only.

Comment: Do one thing, paste your actual JSON in question. so that i can identify problem. you have posted Print value from Debugger.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109550/discussion-between-dipen-panchasara-and-hellosheikh).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your `NSArray` is mainArr.

```
NSString *tripID = @"41";
NSArray *tripIDArr [mainArr valueForKey :@"Trip"]valueForKey : @"trip_id"];
 NSInteger index = [tripIDArr indexOfObject :tripID];
NSDictionary *dict = [mainArr objectAtIndex:index];
```

Try above line of code. Hope it will help you.

Comment: okay I am getting an error. I debug the code. I'll tell you whats printing what 
tripIDArr prints two ids 40 and 41 
when I print out "index" it prints out this
9223372036854775807 

what is this?

Comment: Can you write here result of `po  tripIDArr`?

Comment: this is what is printing

 (
        (
        41,
        40
    )
)

Comment: `NSArray *tripIDArr =[[ [mainArr valueForKey :@"Trip"] lastObject]valueForKey : @"trip_id"];`
Please try above line of code for get `tripIDArr`. and check if not work then write result of `po tripIDArr` here

Comment: could you tell me how to write this line in swift. having trouble converting it into swift

Comment: I am working in swift. I have successfully converted your above answer into swift code but this line I coudn't be able to do that. so can't check

Comment: I do not know swift.please `po  tripIDArr` if possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109512/discussion-between-hellosheikh-and-payal-maniyar).

Answer (score 0):

the json object that you print is `NSArray`(called `standardArr` for example ) of `NSDictionary`. and your expected dictionary is `desiredDict` for example. Now you can do something like this,

```
NSArray *standardArr;  //your array which you have put in your question
NSDictionary *desiredRecord;  //resulting record

for (int i = 0; i < standardArr.count; i++) {

    NSDictionary *tempDict = [standardArr objectAtIndex:i];

    NSDictionary *tempDict2 = [tempDict objectForKey:@"Trip"];

    NSString *strID = [tempDict2 valueForKey:@"trip_id"];

    if ([strID isEqualToString:@"41"]) {


        desiredRecord = tempDict; //if you want whole record

        //or

        desiredRecord = tempDict2;  //if you want only Trip record

        //or

        desiredRecord = [tempDict objectForKey:@" User"]; //if you want User record etc.....

        break;
    }

}
```

Convert it in swift and i don't think is hard task..!

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

When you receive JSON data, there is nothing that forces you to keep the data in the exact form you need it. It's actually a bad idea usually. Most people would define a model class that contains userID, tripID, tripPostDate, firstName, lastName and so on, and instead of returning an array of dictionaries, verify all the incoming data, and create an array of model objects.

If you often need to access one such model object by its tripID, you just create a dictionary mapping tripID to model objects and lookup the object in that dictionary - once the dictionary is created, any lookup is very fast even with thousands of trips.